# UITableView displaying incorrectly but data is passed in

Tags: uitableview, ios5, xcode4.3

I have a UITableView fetching data from HTML. The fetching is working fine, and I usually have about 20 cells to display, from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, up to 20.

However, after the fetching, the cells only shows the content in the first cell on all the cells. (i.e. 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) If I scroll down, I'll see 6, 7, 8, ... , 20. And if I scroll back up again, I'll see the table become normal...

I was testing the code, and I found out in the insertNewObject class if I insert at 0 Index, then everything will be normal. However, not if I simply add object nor insert object at the last index works for me.

Here is my code for insertNewObject class:

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

// Working code, but I want the order from the top 1, 2, 3, ..., 20 rather than 
// 20, 19, 18, ..., 2, 1
// [_objects insertObject:sender atIndex:0];

// And the code below doesn't show up correctly...
//    [_objects insertObject:sender atIndex:(_objects.count)];
//    [_objects addObject:sender];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

It's very weird, I think it's something to do with drawing because the UITableView shows everything fine if I keep scrolling up and down and "clean" the display... but if I do setDisplay, nothing happened at all... Refreshing the table doesn't solve the problem neither...

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Ok... I've done something very stupid...

I made an array, put them in first, and the reversely looping and put them into the UITable with [_objects insertObject:sender atIndex:0];

It's a solution, but I don't think it's the right way. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough context in your question to know for sure, but I think maybe you are trying to do too work here.  You can use the `NSMutableArray` method `addObject:` to append your new object to the end of your data array.  After doing that you should be able to just call `reloadData` and your tableView will redraw itself to include a cell for your new data item.

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } 
    [_objects addObject:sender];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I tried this method but it still shows 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 8, 9, ..., 20... I'll have to "clear" the cells by scrolling up and down and it will return 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ..., 20... It's very weird... Never experienced this before when I work with UITable...